# Time Complexity Explanation

Tags: time, binary, complexity-theory

Can someone please explain how to find the time complexity of this algorithm
I think its O(logN) because of the binary splits, but im not sure

```
    int findRotationCount(int a[], int sizeOfArray) //O(logN)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int endValue = sizeOfArray -1;

        while(start<endValue)
        {
            if(a[start] < a[endValue])
                return endValue+1;
            else
            {
                int mid = (start+endValue)/2;

                if(a[start]<=a[mid] && a[mid+1]<=a[endValue])
                    return mid+1;
                else if(a[start]<=a[mid])
                    start = mid+1;
                else
                    endValue = mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, each loop of the `while` reduces the range `start` to `endValue` to (roughly) half the size, so it is `O(log n)`. Look for the analysis of e.g. binary search, which has a similar structure if you need more details.